# Передать переменную в html

Tags: php

На php пишу:

```
$name = $row['first_name'];
$welcomeblock = file_get_contents('./blocks/profile/welcome.min', true);
require_once('./blocks/profile/profile.min');
```

Происходит так, что выводится profile.min, где такой код:

```
<div class="frame">
    <?php
         echo $welcomeblock;
    ?>
</div>
```

То есть читается php переменная, которая выводится через html. Здесь все в порядке. Дальше читается welcomeblock из файла welcome.min, а там:

```
<div id = "startpage">
    Здравствуйте, <?php echo $name; ?>!<br>
    Выберите пункт в меню
</div>
```

И вот на этом месте после здравствуйте ничего не выводится, хотя php получает не пустой name. Что можно сделать, чтобы имя все-таки выводилось?
Все то же самое с любыми другими переменными, которые были получены таким образом: переменная из php в блок кода из php, который подгружается в общий код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут скорее всего дело в том что вы получаете СОДЕРЖИМОЕ welcome.min, которое, в отличии от profile.min, не включается в исполняемый скрипт, соответственно и не исполняется интерпретатором. Могу быть не точен, но насколько мне известно, когда вы подключаете файл при помощи require - он становится частью скрипта. То есть это то же самое что вставить в место строчки `require_once('./blocks/profile/profile.min')` содержимое этого файла, поэтому для файлов подключенных при помощи `require_once` происходит выполнение всех php инструкций. Решить данную проблему, как мне кажется, можно следующими способами:

**1)** В файле, содержимое которого вы получаете при помощи file_get_contents, вместо php инструкций использовать некие ключевые слова (например, {name}), означающие переменные, которые потом можно будет заменить на значения этих самых переменных при помощи функции str_replace.

```
$welcomeblock = str_replace(['{name}','{surname}'],[$name,$surname],$welcomeblock);
```

**2)** Подключать файл welcome.min при помощи того же require или include, но при этом использовать перед подключением `ob_start();` чтобы при подключении файла все что будет отдано им, не выводилось но было возвращено как строка при помощи функции `ob_get_clean();`, которую следует вызвать после.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!
Выбрал первый вариант, так как второй не очень удобен (нужно было бы делить код)